# pandas: create a date time column from an existing date time column

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, datetime

I am trying to create a new datetime column from an existing date time column in a pandas data frame. Here is my code:

```
import datetime
pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'])
df['end_date'] = df['start_date'] + datetime.timedelta(days=10)
```

But I got the following errors:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, datetime.timedelta found
```

What did I do wrong here and how do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'])` doesn't modify your existing DataFrame, it returns a new Series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something with `Timedelta` like

```
df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.start_date) + pd.Timedelta(10 , unit = 'D')
```